# Converting floor plans into hierarchical graphs

Tags: java, xml, graph

I'm developing a navigation application for android. I need to convert the floor map into a hierarchical graph. As far as I know after converting the map into a graph this will produce an XML file presenting the rooms as nodes. I have searched about hierarchical graph  but all I got was theoretical explanation of the graphs.

While searching also I read something about GoogleOpenStreet. I read that it can be used to convert floor plans into graphs but also I didn't find anything about how to do it.

Can anyone suggest methods to do this using Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I found a solution, and no one answered it. I will answer it to help other people who have the same problem.

I didn't find a direct method to convert floor plans into hierarchical graphs, instead I used a  [graph editor](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html) to draw a graph that represent the floor plan and then used the resulting  file ( which is similar to XML format) and parsed in.